# Internal DNS address for Google Cloud internal load balancers

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

According to this [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/internal-dns), every VM instance has a DNS entry of the following form:

```
hostName.c.[PROJECT_ID].internal
```

This would look something like:

```
redis.c.myproject.internal
```

I want to know if there is an equivalent for internal load balancers. Looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/), there doesn't seem to be anything, but that looks like a pretty big oversight.

So, is there a way to access an internal LB in GCP via a DNS entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no entry in the GCE DNS metadata server for LBs. There is an open feature request for this at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904974. You can Star that request to signal your interest and subscribe to updates.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out how to star that issue, but thank you so much for finding that. Apparently, there is a workaround for that by creating a static IP - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#creating_an_internal_load_balancer_with_a_static_internal_ip_address.

Comment: First you need to sign in with a Google account. Then you need to click the star icon; see https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do this with `Cloud DNS`

Create Zone and then add your IP, it can be anything from VM to LB. whatever you want to resolve under VPC.

[image]